# How do you get the current scenario and/or spec name when running selenium with gauge

Tags: java, selenium, getgauge

I am working with gauge and trying to get the current spec and/or scenario name. Currently my code is structured similarly to the java-maven-selenium example that gauge has put up in github.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`BeforeScenario`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.thoughtworks.gauge/gauge-java/0.6.5/com/thoughtworks/gauge/BeforeScenario.html) hook and [`ExecutionContext`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.thoughtworks.gauge/gauge-java/0.6.5/com/thoughtworks/gauge/ExecutionContext.html) to get this information.

An example:

```
@BeforeScenario
public void beforeScenario(ExecutionContext context){
    System.out.println("Current Spec: " + context.getCurrentSpecification().getName());
    System.out.println("Current Scenario: " + context.getCurrentScenario().getName());
}
```